# Apache Spark: How many partitions can a executor hold in spark.? How are the partitions distributed (mechanism) among the executors?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am interested to know the following nitty gritties of spark parallelism and Partitioning

1. How many partitions can a executor hold in spark?
2. How are the partitions distributed (mechanism) among the executors?
3. How to set the size of the partition. Would like to know the relevant the config parameter.
4. Does executor store all the partitions in memory? If not when spilled to disk does it spill entire partition to disk or a part of partition to disk?
   5 When there are 2 cores per executor but there are 5 partition in that executor then

Comment: Think my answer is good enuff.

Comment: No, I prefer others to answer too

Comment: An executor hold nothing is completely wrong, it does hold some part of RDD. Please revisit the documentation or other blogs

Comment: do you find out answers to all above questions? I am also curious about them.

Answer (score 2):

Not quite the right way to look at it. An Executor holds nothing, it just does work.

- A Partition is processed by a Core that has been assigned to an Executor. An Executor typically has 1 core but can have more than 1 such Core.
- An App has Actions that translate to 1 or more Jobs.
- A Job has Stages (based on Shuffle Boundaries).
- Stages have Tasks, the number of these depends on number of Partitions.
- Parallel processing of the Partitions depends on number of Cores allocated to Executors.

Spark is scalable in terms of Cores, Memory and Disk. The latter two in relation to your questions means that if the Partitions cannot all fit into Memory on the Worker for your Job, then that Partition or more will spill in its entirety to Disk.

Comment: A executor which is a JVM process dedicates some if its memory to hold the data of RDD/DF/DS  chunks called partitions. If not may I know where do u say the partitions of RDD/DF/DS are stored? Please remember spark strong hold is in memory processing as long as data fits.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me. The idea is to process things in memory, but if you do not request / have enough resources in terms of memory, then spilling occurs to disk, HDFS. What else can you do?

Comment: I agree that. But lets talk about the scenario where things fit in memory in that case where are the partitions of RDD if not in executors? Also even if there is a spill to disk, partitions will be loaded back into memory when its the turn of the partition in disk to get executed by task, now in this case where do you say they get loaded if not into executor memory?

Comment: Things get paged out and paged in in old speak. One partition will be stored on disk, the other to be processed by the Executor now, will be read in. And so forth.

Comment: I agree so when the page in happens and a partition is loaded into memory where is it? Is it not in Executor(JVM)? Is it outside JVM, if yes then u say a program of JVM is accessing object out side JVM ? JVM defines all object to be executed in it

Comment: Well it depends where u r in the data pipeline. If the file/files are being read from HDFS, it will only be on that data store. If you have read the partition in already and it has been processed, optimized in the Stage as a task and there is no room, then it will written out to disk / HDFS. When the next Stage starts, it will necessarily read those partitions in, that are not in memory, from disk.  And so on. Spark also needs to manage resources like an OS.

Comment: BTW: A Stage must finish all Tasks before the next Stage commences.

Comment: Stuff runs in the JVM, pyspark differs if I remember correctly.

Comment: That's correct tasks are accepted by an executor. Executors run on a JVM. When you have multiple executors on the same Hardware, then those executors will share the same JVM instance and will share the same memory.